# what should i do after openid (or twitter ,facebook) user login my site ,on gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid, integration

how to integration local user and openid(or facebook twitter) user ,

did you know some framework have already done this ,

**updated**

my mean is : how to deal with 'local user' and 'openid user',

and how to mix them in one model .

please give me a framework  that realize  'local user' and 'openid user'

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question is very vague, and seems like you're asking SO users to do your work for you.

Comment: you only need to give me a framework ,i want see its source

Comment: you only need to give us an understandable question

Comment: you seem to think that there is a framework for everything, and that software development consists of asking SO users to find the framework for you. That's not the case. There probably doesn't exist a framework for this, and it's up to you to do it. So do it. Come back when you have specific questions to ask, and after you've tried to fix the problems yourself. SO users (myself included) have better things to do than to be your pair programming partner. And answer some other SO users' questions. Contribute something!

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question.

You wish to be able to maintain a list of users that have signed up with your service, and also want to record users using OpenID to authenticate.

In order to solve this I would do either of the following:

- Create a new user in your users table for each new user logged in under OpenID, and store their OpenID in this table to allow you to join the two.
- Move your site to OpenID and change all references to your current users to OpenID users.

I'd probably go with Option 1 if you already have this app in production.

**Note: More experienced Open ID users will probably correct me!**